# Attempting to merge in an array of items into Twig classes

Tags: 8, theming, taxonomy-terms, debugging

I have a Twig template where I'd like to merge in an array of items as classes. So far I have this code:

```
{% set classes = [
  'media',
  'media--type-' ~ media.bundle()|clean_class,
  not media.isPublished() ? 'media--unpublished',
  view_mode ? 'media--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
] %}


 {% for item in content.field_category | children(true) %}
   {% set classes = classes|merge(item) %}
 {% endfor %}

<section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

etc...
```

***Note*** that `{% for item in content.field_category | children(true) %}` is using Twig Tweak.

In this case for example, `item` represents term values for each item in plain text as:

```
Nature 
Travel
Architecture
```

and then with `<section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>`, I'd like the set classes as well as my custom classes to all be merged together. However, I am getting an error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeArray->__toString() (line 73 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/AttributeArray.php).
```

So this tells me, I did not merge the array of items properly but I am lost after this, not sure how to fix it. My guess is, I need to do this without a `for` loop somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twig's merge filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/merge.html) expects an array as an argument, not a string.

Updating your for loop should resolve:

```
{% for item in content.field_category|children(true) %}
  {# Merge classes array with an array with one item, item #}
  {% set classes = classes|merge([item]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe you could also just do `{% set classes = classes|merge(content.field_category|children(true)) %}`

Comment: Thank you this worked, I actually needed to do: 

```{% for item in content.field_category | children(true) %} 
  {% set classes = classes|merge([item["#plain_text"]]) %} 
{% endfor %}``` 

... as that was the actual item in Xdebug. Thank you!

Comment: As you are using Twig Tweak you could use `with` filter like this `{%set classes = classes|with(item) %}`